# javascript/jquery stop button to change play button to initial state not pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, playback, soundmanager2

I am using **Soundmanager2** to play mp3 files. I have a `play` button which toggles with `pause`. and a separate `stop` button.

Press '`play`', music plays and button has toggled to 'Pause'. Press '`pause`' button and music pauses. Works great. Here is my problem:

Press '`Play`' music plays and button changes to a '`pause`' button. Press `Stop` and music stops. That's great but the play button is still as a 'pause' button. Pressing it swicthes it back to play and then a second click plays the music again.

I need to somehow under the stop button code below, reset the play button to it's initial state when the stop button is pressed?

I tried adding '`iteration=1`' under the stop code but this doesn't work.

Here is the javascript code:

```
$(function(){
$('.a5play').click(function(){
var iteration=$(this).data('iteration')||1
switch ( iteration) {

case 1:
soundManager.play('mySound1');
$('.a5play').text('Pause');
break;

case 2:
soundManager.pause('mySound1');
$('.a5play').text('Play');

break;

}
iteration++;
if (iteration>2) iteration=1
$(this).data('iteration',iteration)
})
})

$('.a5stop').click(function(){
        interation=1;
        soundManager.stop('mySound1');

                    });
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Try setting up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for that so we can see how it works ?

Comment: I tried a fiddle but with no luck, sorry...just doesn't want to work. I have found I can change the text back to play just by adding: `$('.a5play').text('Play');` under the stop function. But the audio still only plays on a second click. I think the `stop` function needs to Set the iteration variable back to 1, but I don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try coding an alternative approach to this and got it to work as required. As it may be helpful for others, here is what I have created:

```
 var playbackState = 0;

 /*0 = play*/
 /*1 = pause*/
    $('.a5play').click(function(){
       if(playbackState == "0") {
playbackState="1";
soundManager.play('mySound1');
$('.a5play').text('Pause');
       } else {
playbackState="0";
soundManager.pause('mySound1');
$('.a5play').text('Play');
       }
    });
    $('.a5stop').click(function(){
       playbackState="0";
       soundManager.stop('mySound1');
       $('.a5play').text('Play');
    });
```